# pysqlite's IntegrityError: distinguish 'NOT NULL' from 'UNIQUE' violation

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

In pysqlite, violating a `NOT NULL` or a `UNIQUE` constraint likewise raise an IntegrityError.
Unfortunately, this Exception type does not provide an error code, but only a message.

So, let's say I want to ignore unique-constraint violations, because I know this is safe on the given data, but Null values in the key columns should be reported.

I've come up with the following solution:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(':MEMORY:')
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE ABCD (A TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  B TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  C TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  D TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (A, B))''')
with con:
    for a, b, c, d in inputs:
        try:
            con.execute('INSERT INTO ABCD VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                        (a, b, c, d))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            # Skip 'not unique' errors, but raise others.
            if not e.message.endswith('not unique'):
                raise
con.close()
```

However, parsing the error message seems wrong and might be unreliable.
Is there a better way to do this, maybe even using `con.executemany()`?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But I wonder what use a constraint is if it can be safely ignored? Why don't just drop it? In your example code `(A, B)` is you PK. I think that this constraint must not be ignored. What would be a real world use case?

Comment: The unique constraint is not ignored, the input lines are. The input is expected to contain duplicates on those fields, and I'm skipping repetitions silently.

Comment: You could filter the input and remove all duplicates before passing it ti SQLite.

Comment: Yes, sure, but then I'd have to build an extra index of the primary keys first, before inserting them to the db, which was going to index them anyway.

Comment: It is *much easier* to just pre-filter your data on NULL values in the key column. Ignoring the non-unique keys is as easy as using `INSERT OR IGNORE` then.

Comment: Looking at the pysqlite and sqlite3 source code, indicates that the return error code you are seeking is [#define SQLITE_CONSTRAINT  19](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) and is the same for all constraint violations regardless of constraint type.This along with SQLITE_MISMATCH gets mapped to a pysqlite [IntegrityException](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/ad262bd83b7b562d3198e456df2b445e5e56ef80/src/util.c).Parsing the error message associated with that exception seems like the only way to distinguish the cases without adding new functionality to both the binding and sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters, that's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(':MEMORY:')
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE ABCD (A TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  B TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  C TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  D TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (A, B))''')
with con:
    for a, b, c, d in inputs:
        if any(elem is None for elem in (a, b, c, d)):
            raise ValueError('Fields must not be empty.')
        con.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ABCD VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    (a, b, c, d))
con.close()
```

Like this, empty values are caught "manually" before executing the DB operation. If any error occurs during `execute` (such as a violation of the `UNIQUE` constraint), the entry is skipped. Please note that `INSERT OR IGNORE` does not mean ignoring the uniqueness constraint, but rather ignoring (ie. skipping) an input line.

The downside of this solution is that the check for empty values is done twice. I guess this is not too bad however, since it is presumably rather cheap an operation. I think, it is still cleaner than parsing the error message, and probably more robust to changes (such as a pysqlite update, which might change some detail in the error message).

Credits: The idea emerged from discussion with Lutz. It was independently also suggested by Martijn.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution is to rely on SQL(ite) functionality entirely.
By specifying a conflict clause for the primary key (`ON CONFLICT IGNORE`), the desired behaviour is already achieved:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE ABCD (A TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  B TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  C TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  D TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (A, B) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)''')
```

Thus, duplicate lines (which violate the uniqueness constraint of the primary key) are silently skipped, while Null values cause an abort (resulting in an `sqlite3` exception). This is all achieved without pre-filtering the data for Null/None values or fiddling with error messages of the `sqlite3` API.
We can now simply call `con.executemany()`, without further ado:

```
with con:
    con.executemany('INSERT INTO ABCD VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', inputs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is a working code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE ABCD (A TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  B TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  C TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  D TEXT NOT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (A, B));''')

inputs = [('cow', 'pig', 'cat', 'dog'), ('cow', 'pig', 'quail', 'turkey')]
with con:
    for a, b, c, d in inputs:
        try:
            con.execute('INSERT INTO ABCD VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);',
                        (a, b, c, d))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            if 'not null' in e.args[0].lower():
                print('There is a NULL value')
            elif 'unique constraint' in e.args[0].lower():
                print('There is unique violation')
            else:
                raise
```

Test:

```
>>> 
There is a NULL value
>>>
```

Second Test result:

```
>>> 
There is unique violation
>>>
```

Hopes, can help you.

Comment: The question asks for a way that is *better* than parsing the error message.

Comment: This code does not ignore UNIQUE constraint violations.

Comment: @CL.  I've edit my answer to catch NULL and UNIQUE violation.